# Is there a way to set which heroku stack (20 for ex.) with the deploy button url?

Tags: heroku

I am using Heroku's deploy button feature, but in order for my app to work, it needs to be set to the Heroku 20 stack.

Is there a way to do that within the url of the button?

Take a look at the deploy button on this page: https://github.com/stripe/example-terminal-backend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku's deploy buttons are powered by a file called `app.json`. This file can optionally [specify the stack to use](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/app-json-schema#stack):

> **stack**
>
> *(string, optional)* The [Heroku stack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/stack) on which the app will run. If this is not specified, the [default stack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/stack#default-stack) will be used.
>
> ```
> {
>   "stack": "heroku-20"
> }
> ```

I suspect you don't have permission to modify that file in the repository you're linking to, but you should be able to [fork it](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/quickstart/fork-a-repo) and add a `stack` key to its `app.json` file.

Make sure to update the link in your README, too. The repo you've forked links to

```
https://heroku.com/deploy?template=https://github.com/stripe/example-terminal-backend
```

but you'll want to change the `template` argument to point to your fork.

Comment: Thanks Chris! which repository should be forked?

Comment: You're trying to deploy [the repo in the question](https://github.com/stripe/example-terminal-backend), right? That's what you'd have to fork, so you can modify its `app.json` file.

Comment: Thanks. Does the below look right?
`{
  "name": "Example Terminal Backend",
  "description": "For testing the Stripe Terminal SDK example apps. https://stripe.com/docs/terminal",
  "repository": "https://github.com/stripe/example-terminal-backend",
  "keywords": ["ios", "android", "javascript", "stripe", "terminal", "stripe terminal"],
  "env": {
    "STRIPE_TEST_SECRET_KEY": {
      "description": "Find this at https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys (it'll look like sk_test_****)",
      "required": true
    },
    {
  "stack": "heroku-20"
}
  }
}`

Comment: (Please forgive me - I dont know how to format comments.)

Comment: @JayF, it's hard to read code in comments but I think you want to lose the `{}` around your stack and move it out of the `env` value. It should be at the same level as `name`, `description`, etc.

Comment: Thanks so much Chris! Take a look at this file: https://github.com/SwissMediaRocks/example-terminal-backend/blob/master/app.json

I'm still getting the same error - it is showing `-----> Building on the Heroku-22 stack`

Comment: Why are you trying to use the Heroku 18 stack? Your question says you need to use Heroku 20. [Heroku 18 is no longer supported](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/stack#stack-support-details).

Comment: I got the same response when using heroku-20. I was just trying 18 as well and left it there.

Comment: Ah, you'll have to edit your `README.md`, too. The link in your still refers to the upstream repo. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Holy cow! That’s so silly of me and I appreciate your help so much!